# How to find the bug line/file in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, debugging

I am following the hero tutorial on Angular's page. I have come to Routing step so far. Now my script does not work. I see only "Loading..." text as default template. There is an error in some file. But I cannot see where the script stops flowing.

I need to be warned/informed that the computer should tell me "there is an error in file 'somefile.js' at line 99".

I do not know how to find the line to be corrected. And I want to see where the app halts. Is there a way to find it on console or firebug or something else?

This is important when I start to develop my own scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you have the web dev tools stop on exception?

with Chrome

- open developer tools
- open sources tab
- click stop icon with || inside it (top right of dev tools above call stack)

This will cause your app to pause on all exceptions.